# Azure DB Sync: Sync multiple hub-member pairs with a single shared sync database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have multiple Azure database sync groups set up currently using the member database of each group as the sync database however this causes issues when trying to make certain changes e.g. renaming the databases.

Is it possible to have multiple one to one hub-member sync groups share a common sync database? Will this cause any issues with the syncing for any reason? If so what is the best practice when attempting something like this?

Comment: Do you mean if you can have many member databases all syncing to one hub database?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is possible with no negative effects that we can see at the moment.